# Como expandir la cantidad de datos que se puede recibir en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, angularjs

El caso es que en mi aplicación deseo generar un reporte y al ser mas de 300 datos me sale un error y al parecer es por que no aguanta mas de 200 datos extraídos desde una consulta en SQL server, yo uso C# con angular y utilizo entity Framework, es un app web.

Pensé que se podría arreglar el error en web config pero nada me sirve 
  
intenté con esto pero nada..

Comment: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"  useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="65536" requestLengthDiskThreshold="24576" executionTimeout="3600"/>  CON ESTO NO ME SIRVE

Comment: me pregunto, el usuario va a poder procesar visualmente 300 registros ? esta claro que no, porque no evaluas paginar los datos o proporcionarle al usuario mejores filtros. Si es un reporte, usa tools de reporting, no una pagina web

Comment: Si el problema es que el usuario necesita ver primero en una tabla y luego ya imprimir el reporte (eso y a lo hace), el sistema es todo web por eso el reporte así

Comment: Cuando dices *"eso y a lo hace"* ¿a qué te refieres?

Comment: 300 registros no es practicamente nada, yo creo que debe haber algun error en la consulta, puedes revisar que no esté habilitado lazy loading o que no hay muchos includes mal usados. Pero DEFINITIVAMENTE yo no ampliaría el timeout, no es una solución

Comment: Hola, puedes compartir la definición de las entidades implicadas en la consulta y el código de la misma?

Comment: como respuesta de action en el controller estas retornando una entidad que mapeas en entity framework ? si es asi no evaluaeste mapearla en el linq a una clase que definas como model para que serialice esta a json, esto hara que si esta intentando retornar las relaciones, no lo haga